# How can I find the source code for linux commands?

Tags: command-line, source-code, execute-command, source

I often come across interesting Linux commands that make me wonder; what are these commands actually doing?

Yes, they might be 'force-removing dependencies', 'installing programs' and doing lots of other stuff, but I'd like to know **how** they're doing it.

Looking into the source code seems the right thing to do then, but where am I supposed to get it from?

I suppose they'll be written in C?

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about packages installed using `apt-get`. I'm looking for the source code of linux/unix commands.

Comment: Do you even search? ;)

Comment: I'm not talking about packages installed with `dpkg` or `apt-get`, I'm talking about unix commands...

Comment: Then it's too broad / unclear, which Linux commands? There are tons of them, mantained by tons of different mantainers. `apt-get source` always avails since you can download the packages which provide them and look at their source code from there.

Comment: So the commands are installed by `apt-get`?

Comment: Absolutely, the most common ones for example are provided by `coreutils`.

Comment: I don't get the point of this at all. You want source code for commands you run in `apt`? Commands don't have there own source code they manipulate programs and will be defined in that programs source code. Please do correct me if i am wrong or missing the point..

Comment: @markkirby I want source code for **linux** commands. *Any* command.

Comment: You need to understand something: let's say that you want the source code for `rm`. That's hosted at gnu.org. Then let's say that you want the source code for Perl. That's hosted at perl.org. Can you see the problem with that? We can't put all the links to any known command's mantainer in an answer. The closest you can get to a unique place to get the source code for a command is downloading the package that provides it from the repositories. Other than that the answer is just: it depends on the command, visit the mantainer's website.

Comment: @kos Thanx kos - could you give an answer that sums it all up?

Comment: The question as is phrased is off-topic *and* too broad: "Linux commands" doesn't necessarily pertain to Ubuntu, and the only answer to that would be "visit the command mantainer's website". And to be honest that wouldn't be a great question either. If you're happy with narrowing it down to "Ubuntu's commands" then the question would be fine, but than it would have been answered already in the duplicate I linked. I don't see a way out of this honestly.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Lol, nvm - I tried closing the question myself, but for some reason, it's just counting it as a vote.

Comment: You should have a button with "That solved my problem!" written on it at the top of the question's body, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1MlLj.png). Isn't it there?

Comment: No, since I edited my answer to "explain why"...

Comment: Alright, it doesn't matter, it will be closed by someone else. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about GNU/Debian commands. Linux does not have commands. Most Linux distributions use GNU utilities (that's why we should call them 'GNU/Linux') and their own commands (such as Debian's APT system). For example, in Ubuntu, commands such as `cp`, `cd`, `mv` are part of the GNU Core Utilities, which are part of the Ubuntu core (base) system. They are represented by the package `coreutils`. There is an apt-get paramater that you can use to get packages source code: `apt-get source`. To get coreutils' source code, use `sudo apt-get source coreutils`. It's important to know that commands are nothing more than binaries placed in the paths of the PATH environment variable. These binaries are usually written in C. Also note that commands from some other Unix-like systems, even though they have the same names, are not from the GNU project and sometimes have different syntax. This is the case with the BSD's (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD) and OSX (based in FreeBSD).

Answer (score 4):

Syntax: `apt-get source command-name`

Example: `apt-get source netstat`

If it cannot find:

Add a Source URI to sources.lst

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

`deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian lenny main`

`apt-get update`